# iOS UIReferenceLibraryViewController and dictionary

Tags: ios, dictionary, reference-library

I have two questions regarding UIReferenceLibraryViewController (UIRLVC).

I have an app which is for language education. I want to add dictionary function. One way to implement dictionary function is to use UIRLVC. While reading the class reference, I was confused the following statement:

---

### A UIReferenceLibraryViewController object provides a dictionary service to look up the definition of a word or term from within an app. It should not be used to display wordlists, create a standalone dictionary app, or republish the content in any form.

Can I use this function in my app as dictionary service. Certainly, my app, which is approved, is not only dictionary app, as other functions are included.

Another related question is that, UIRLVC provides dictionary service in the language set by user preference (General -> International -> Language), in another word, in a Spanish-based iPad, you can only look up a Spanish word. What I want in my application is have an English -> German dictionary, for example. I wonder if this is achievable via UIRLVC. If yes, how? If not, what's the alternative and how?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tony, did you ever get an answer whether or not you can use UIReferenceLibraryViewController as a translation dictionary? I just started looking into this. I'm assuming no.

Comment: I didn't go via that way at the end. I used my own dictionary.